# Save Word as PDF - late binding

Tags: vba

I have some code which creates Word files and then saves them in PDF format. When it's in early binding it works well but when I changed to late binding I received a message:

> Invalid procedure call or argument.

Here's my code:

```vba
PlikW.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=Katalog & "\" & Marka & ".pdf", ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False
```

Comment: Show your [mcve] and [edit] the question so it is clear what you want to do, what you have tried, and what results you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it happens is because only early binding allows referring to enumerated constants, `wdExportFormatPDF` in this case, by their names.

You need to replace it with a number, according to the following link it would be 17.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/wdexportformat-enumeration-word

Comment: You can accept an answer in this case, as meta source state: "accepting an answer is important as it both rewards posters for solving your problem and informs others that your issue is resolved". There is no need to post "thanks" comments on Stack Overflow, unless they add some valuable information, there is marking as an answer and upvote system instead.